# What does "supposer quelqu'un avec quelqu'un d'autre" mean?

Tags: sens, usage

I am working with a text which is antiquated and very vague in some places, but I do need to understand the exact meaning. There is a passage that simply escapes me, no matter how much I search the dictionaries. I can of course guess and invent, but I was wondering if anyone is aware of a more ancient use and meaning of the French verb "supposer":

[image]

(*[Analecta Bollandiana](https://archive.org/stream/analecta-bollandiana-1-126/Analecta%20Bollandiana%20103%2C%201985_djvu.txt)*)

C'est en fait le texte d'une note de bas de page et le contexte est un peu compliqué, mais je vais quand-même le citer ici, comme on me l'a suggéré dans les commentaires.

[image]

Ce texte est traduit de l'arménien mentionné dans la note.

Comment: There is an unpublished translation, apparently: This Byzantine hagiographical  life of Constantine was discovered and published with an introduction and notes (but without a translation) as F. Halkin, Une nouvelle vie de Constantin dans un légendier de Patmos, Analecta Bollandiana 77 (1959): 63-107.  Halkin dates it to the 9th century or later.  This otherwise unpublished English translation is copyright to Professor Samuel N.C. Lieu (Macquarie University,Sydney, and Wolfson College, Cambridge)

Comment: and appears by permission. Selected abbreviated notes have been added by me (RP) from Halkin’s footnotes. Actually, it says otherwise unpublished. Maybe that can help. I don't get that poor translation from the Armenian.

Comment: Thing is, it's a bit of a comvoluted matter. This is about the life of a saint Herakleidios from Cyprus included here. It was originally written in Greek, but was lost and now the closest to the original is this Armenian translation that now they are trying to restore into Greek - unfortunately through French (too vague in some places). Who knows Armenian and Greek... :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that it is a specific ancient usage but just  an ellipsis for a sentence like:

> F. Halkin **a pu supposer** [que] **Macedonia** [avait un lien] **avec Grégoire** (avait pour fils Grégoire).

F. Halkin might have guessed that Macedonia was related to Gregory (was his mother).

Halkin supports this assumption from the interpretation of the Greek text quoted in the footnote that talks about "his son Gregorios" and the original Armenian text.

---

Je ne crois pas qu'il s'agisse d'un usage ancien mais plus simplement d'une ellipse pour quelque chose comme :

> F. Halkin **a pu supposer** [que] **Macedonia** [avait un lien] **avec Grégoire**, avait pour fils Grégoire.

Halkin appuie cette supposition sur l'interprétation du texte grec cité dans la note de bas de page, texte  qui parle de "son fils Gregorios", et du texte arménien original.

Comment: Dommage qu'il ait fait une telle ellipse, si vague. Ce que vous dites, je l'avais supposé aussi. Et si deux y pensent, la probabilité est plus grande que l'intention de l'auteur soit celle-ci en effet.

Comment: Si on remplace *supposer* par *imaginer*, dont le sens est proche, il me semble que la phrase ne pose plus vraiment de problème: *François Halkin a pu imaginer Macedonia avec Grégoire.*

Comment: Je dirais même _**associée avec Grégoire**_. Mais c'est quand même une ellipse étrange!

Comment: J'espère que c'est pas encore _Armance_ haha. Ça serait alors peut-être comme _poser (que)_, un peu comme affirmer que. Je comprends pas trop le contexte.